# What to do if i skipped mok management twice?

Tags: boot, grub2, package-management, bios, secure-boot

system info - `Linux xxxxx 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. grub 2.04`

I did the typical `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` yesterday and upon reboot I was prompted with the mok management blue screen. This had happened to me once earlier as well. I remembered selecting continue and things working fine so, I did the same this time around as well. Now, I read up on the issue and it seems there are a few modules that are not signed and won't be loaded up by bios before I sign them manually or disable secure boot.

Questions:

1. Am i right in understanding the issue?
2. What do i do now? Do I leave it as is, disable the secure boot or sign the modules myself? I know how to leave it as is (boooyaah) and how to disable the secure boot. But if I should sign the modules myself, how do I go about finding the modules that need signing and sign them?